# python regex not match last char

Tags: python

Im Trying to match numbers separated by / inside [], but the last char is not included, why is this? but without the /

```
import re
regex = r"\[.+?\]"
Sample1= "text text text[One]"
Sample2= "text text text[One/Two]"
Sample3= "text text text[One/Two/Three]"
lines=[Sample1,Sample2,Sample3]
print([re.findall(r"\[(.+?)[^\/]\]", s) for s in lines])
```

and the out put now is:

```
[['On'], ['One/Tw'], ['One/Two/Thre']]
```

and I wanted to be:

```
[['One'], ['One', 'Two'], ['One','Two','Three']]
```

What wold be the correct regex?

Comment: Because the last character that's not matching one of the others isn't inside your capturing group...

Comment: `print([re.findall(r"\[(.+[^\/])\]", s) for s in lines])`

Comment: Thanks, I added to the question what would be the correct regex? I understand the reason now

Comment: Did you ask this to try and fix an answer you've given to another question? :p

Comment: Is that forbidden? No rules say that, is a fail in the system, not my fault hahahaha

Comment: Not at all... I was just "umm.... sure I've seen that data before"... then "umm... why are they asking if they've answered the one I've seen before" :p

Comment: Might wanna remove that last bit from your comment - people will take that quite seriously... Anyway - the other answers on that post have regexes that will do what you intended to ask :)

Comment: @JonClements yes but I wanted to do my own research with explain, if I don't do that I wont learn ever... thanks by the way, you rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matches = [re.findall(r"\[(.+[^\/])\]", s) for s in lines]
print(matches)
```

This will work. I have corrected the regex.

Comment: sreem, I updated the answer, do you know how to separate without /?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I will need to experiment and find out. For a simple solution without regex you can run a loop and split the string based on `'/'`